# How to delete data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm working with Firebase and AngularJS and I need to delete random generated id in Realtime Database.

```
var todoFirebaseID;
//add Firebase
$scope.addFirebase = function() {
    var objects = {
        title: objectTitle.value,
        content: objectContent.value
    }

    var list = $firebaseArray(storageRef);
    list.$add(objects).then(function(storageRef) {
        todoFirebaseID = storageRef.key;

        $scope.addTodo();
    });
}
// Remove Firebase
$scope.removeFirebase = function() {
    var obj = $firebaseObject(storageRef);
    obj.$remove().then(function() {

    });
}
```

I tried it, but it deletes all data in Firebase. I need to delete only the selected data.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Firebase to remove the entire database, so that's precisely what it does. If you only want to remove a single item, you should invoke `$remove()` on that specific item.

The only way that I can see deleting an item from the code you shared is:

```
$scope.removeFirebase = function() {
    var obj = $firebaseObject(storageRef.child(todoFirebaseID));
    obj.$remove();
}
```

So we're passing in a reference to the `todoFirebaseID` child item.

In a more realistic app, you'd trigger a handler when the user clicks the delete button and then that handler would figure out the ID of the item the user clicked on.